# Counting tags in different cells and sum them

Tags: excel, tags, sum

So I have a lot of rows in an Excel spreadsheet, which includes different stuff. Basically it looks like this:

```
  Element 1    |  Element 2    |  Tags
------------------------------------------------
  Example 1.1  |  Example 1.2  |  tag1,tag2,tag5
  Example 2.1  |  Example 2.2  |  tag2,tag4,tag6
  Example 3.1  |  Example 3.2  |  tag1,tag3,tag6
  Example 4.1  |  Example 4.2  |  tag1,tag3,tag5
  Example 5.1  |  Example 5.2  |  tag1,tag4,tag5
```

So just ignore the stuff in the first two columns, for what I'm asking, this is not important. However, the last column (Tags), the thing I would like to is count all the rows/cells with tags, and then just sum it up, so I get (in this case) the following:

```
tag1: 4
tag5: 3
tag2: 2
tag3: 2
tag4: 2
tag6: 2
```

So in principle, just find how many of each tag there is in all cells selected, and the sum it up and spit out the numbers of each tag. Can this be done in Excel?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an array formula to do this like:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("tag1", C:C)),1,0))
```

After putting in the formula you need to press ctrl + shift + Enter to make the formula an array formula. Excel will automatically add curly brackets '{...}' to indicate it's and array formula.

This assumes that your tags are in column c as per your example you can reference a cell for "tag1" e.g.

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A10, C:C)),1,0))
```

Where A10 has your tag value

In order to get a list of tags the following VBA should do the trick (this loops through a selected range and writes the results to a worksheet called Tags you may need to create this worksheet):

```
Sub GetTags()
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    '
    Dim cellTags() As String
    Dim tag As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    For Each cell In selectedRange.Cells
        cellTags = Split(cell.Value, ",")
        For Each tag In cellTags
            If Not dict.Exists(Trim(tag)) Then
                dict.Add Trim(tag), Trim(tag)
            End If

        Next tag
    Next cell

    Dim StartRow, i As Long
    StartRow = 1
    For i = 0 To (dict.Count - 1)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tags").Range("A" & i + StartRow).Value = dict.Items(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: But would this not require me to know all tags? I currently have like 10.000 cells with different tags. And I don't have a list of all tags at the moment.

Comment: FWIW array formulas should avoid full column references as they will iterate over 1 million times per formula.  That can be a drag on the calc times.

Comment: @DenverDang you will need vba with a dictionary or collection to iterate through each cell and collect the unique tags.

Comment: @DenverDang I agree with Scott a vba routine will be required, also I think his solution would be simpler

Comment: Yes, I kind of figured. But my VBA skills are crazy bad, so maybe I have to figure something out in Python instead :D Thanks anyways...

Comment: @DenverDang I have edited my answer to include a VBA solution to getting all tags

Answer (score 2):

You can use COUNTIF():

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,"*" & "tag1" & "*")
```